# serverfault main formatting has a problem in Chrome Browser

Tags: bug, status-completed

Looks like there is some type of problem in the site forwarding for some reason.  Could this be some type of missing style sheet or something because in my browser, it renders nothing like the other SE sites this morning, even the serverfault meta site.

[image]

Comment: Shift-Refresh? It has looked fine for me all day.

Comment: Which Key is that on a chrome browser.

Comment: Hold down shift, and click the refresh icon, to the left of the address bar.

Comment: nope...didn't fix it.  I have tried to clear out my cache, and restart the browser without effect.  meta.serverfault.com is OK, but serverfault.com has bad formatting.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: different browser (opera,IE are ok) it is just chrome.

Comment: Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: Could you add a picture?

Comment: Windows Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m here, no such problems. Have you any ad-block extensions, or other, installed?

Comment: I have included a picture.  Remember all other SE sites are OK, it is just ServerFAult SE (even meta.serverfault.com is ok).

Comment: If you all have any suggestions to get the standard formatting, PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used CCcleaner to clear out all the caches, and the funny formatting has gone away.
Really Weird.

Comment: That's the mobile site you're seeing

Comment: If I get into that problem again, what do you suggest that I do?

Comment: @mdpc In the mobile layout, at the bottom in the footer, there is a link named "full site". In the full version, the link is named "mobile".